# How can I solve "XMLHttpRequest cannot load javascript"?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome, laravel-5.3

My view is like this :

```
@foreach($product->photo_list as $i => $photo)
    <a href="javascript:" class="text-danger confirm-delete"
       data-toggle="modal"
       data-target="#modal-delete-image"
       data-photo="{{ json_encode($photo) }}" 
       data-product_id="{{ $product->id }}"
    >
        <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
    </a>
@endforeach
```

My modal is like this :

```
<bs-modal id="modal-delete-image" v-cloak>
    <h4 slot="title" class="modal-title">...</h4>
    <div slot="body" class="modal-body">
       ...
    </div>
    <div slot="footer" class="modal-footer">
        ...
    </div>
</bs-modal>
```

My javascript is like this :

```
$(document).on("click", ".confirm-delete", function () {
    var photo = $(this).data('photo');
    var product_id = $(this).data('product_id');
    console.log(photo)
    console.log(product_id)
});
```

I put the js in global js

When executed the code, it works

The console.log success display the result. It's true

But when in chrome browser, there exist error like this :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load javascript:. Cross origin requests are only
>   supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension,
>   https.

If I check on the firefox browser, there is no error

Why when I use chrome browser, there exist error?

How can I solve it?

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, it makes no sense to make an AJAX request to a `javascript:` URL.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on("click", ".confirm-delete", function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var photo = $(this).data('photo'); 
    var product_id = $(this).data('product_id');
     console.log(photo);
     console.log(product_id);
 });
```